# How to make this syntax better?

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, so here's the (rather simple) tables I'm interested in :

```
|=====================
| objects
|=====================
| id   |   name
|

|=====================
| properties
|=====================
| id   |   name
|

|====================================================
| object_properties
|====================================================
| id   |   object_id   |   property_id   |   value
|
```

What I need to do is :

- Based on an **object** name
- Fetch all **property** Name-Value pairs

And this is my SQL (which, actually fetches quite about everything) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM objects, properties, object_properties 
WHERE 
      objects.name="SOME_VALUE" AND 
      object_properties.object_id = objects.id AND 
      object_properties.property_id = properties.id
```

Does it look any good? What am I doing wrong? I know my SQL skills are close to non-existent, so I'm open to suggestions!

---

**P.S.** Given that the actual query is going to be executed on *huge* dataset, what is the most efficient solution?

Comment: is using `joins` not an option?

Comment: First thing, as per your table `objects.value` doesn't exist

Comment: @SivaCharan True. Decided to change it for SO to make it less confusing... Mea culpa!

Comment: @aclarke Just fixed it.

Comment: Solution lies on index. Use index over objects(name,id) and object_properties(id), properties(id)

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Hmmm... What do you mean? Could you give me an example?

Comment: The id column in the objects_properties table appears to serve no purpose. Get rid of it and form a PK on (object_id,property_id) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended ANSI SQL-92 syntax is to use JOINS.

```
SELECT p.name,op.value
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN object_properties op
    ON o.id=op.object_id
INNER JOIN properties p
    ON p.id=op.property_id

WHERE o.value="SOME_VALUE"
```

What you are doing is also implementing join but has a disadvantage.
Suppose in large query involving multiple tables you miss out the joining condition in your `WHERE` clause. The query would still successfully execute as without the joining condition , SQL will perform a cartesian product between the two tables and return more than correct number of rows.

But in joining by using explicitly mentioned keyword `JOIN` as posted above , if you miss the joining condition as specified after the `ON` clause , the query will throw syntax error saving from debugging for errorneously returned resultset.

Comment: Well, I guess it looks fine. Don't know why but I always tend to avoid using `join`s as if some terrible is gonna happen... lol. Thanks, mate!

Comment: What about performance? Is there anything we could do to the above query in case we need to focus on optimizing it for speed on large datasets?

Comment: For optimisation , see Indexing -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

```
select properties.name, object_properties.value
  from objects
 where objects.name = "SOME_VALUE"
   and object_properties.object_id = objects.id
   and properties.id = object_properties.property_id
```

Since you want the property name and the object property value, those are the only fields in my select list.

Since your key is the object name, that's the starting point to introduce the filter on the name of the object.

From the actual object of interest, follow the chain through the related tables. Since object only relates to object_properties, start with that join. This join immediately makes the value available. One more join is needed to get the name of the property. Bring that out by joining the object property row to the appropriate properties row, allowing you to access the property name.

This syntax, by the way, is "old-style" SQL where the joins and the filters are mixed into one WHERE clause. Modern style splits them apart for clarity, and I'm sure you'll get a few replies showing the more modern syntax ;-)